# Unable to install yeoman generators

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, yeoman, yeoman-generator

I am very new to yeoman. I tried running the `lessapp` yeoman generator, but ran into some weird error. I thought may be it was due to the generator and tried installing another generator `bootstrap-less` but still it throws the same error. The error comes when I either try to hit the space button or the arrow keys or on hitting the enter button.

I am placing the error stack below.

Please let me know where I am going wrong.

I am using npm version - 2.1.6 and node - v0.10.33 version on mac 10.9.5

```
 _-----_
    |       |    .--------------------------.
    |--(o)--|    |    Welcome to Yeoman,    |
   `---------´   |   ladies and gentlemen!  |
    ( _´U`_ )    '--------------------------'
    /___A___\    
     |  ~  |     
   __'.___.'__   
 ´   `  |° ´ Y ` 

Out of the box I include HTML5 Boilerplate, jQuery, and a Gruntfile.js to build your app.
? What more would you like? (Press <space> to select)
❯◉ Bootstrap
 ◯ Less
 ◯ Modernizr


/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/yeoman-environment/node_modules/inquirer/node_modules/rx/dist/rx.all.js:9229
        throw e;
              ^
ReferenceError: parent is not defined
    at AnonymousObserver._onNext (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/yeoman-environment/node_modules/inquirer/node_modules/rx/dist/rx.all.js:4259:63)
    at AnonymousObserver.Rx.AnonymousObserver.AnonymousObserver.next (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/yeoman-environment/node_modules/inquirer/node_modules/rx/dist/rx.all.js:1863:12)
    at AnonymousObserver.Rx.internals.AbstractObserver.AbstractObserver.onNext (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/yeoman-environment/node_modules/inquirer/node_modules/rx/dist/rx.all.js:1795:35)
    at AutoDetachObserverPrototype.next (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/yeoman-environment/node_modules/inquirer/node_modules/rx/dist/rx.all.js:9226:23)
    at AutoDetachObserver.Rx.internals.AbstractObserver.AbstractObserver.onNext (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/yeoman-environment/node_modules/inquirer/node_modules/rx/dist/rx.all.js:1795:35)
    at Subject.Rx.Subject.addProperties.onNext (/BANL1291ec423:bootstrap-less pl1$
```

Answer (score 5):

I've got this solved!
As **benurb** suggested here https://github.com/yeoman/yo/issues/247 I manually patched `rx.all.js` in my `C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\yo\node_modules\yeoman-environment\node_modules\inquirer\node_modules\rx\dist`

You should replace

```
shouldRun = predicate.call(thisArg, value, count++, parent);
```

with

```
shouldRun = predicate.call(thisArg, value, count++, source);
```

on the line 4259

Comment: Worked for the same issue on Ubuntu 14.10

Comment: Resolved the same error on Mac OSX while using bower. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Here's the answer I updated just now to this: [Issue with selection options on MAC terminal (scaffloding web application using YOMEN)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27416779/issue-with-selection-options-on-mac-terminal-scaffloding-web-application-using/27417886#27417886)

> Time of writing: [2014.12.11 1:42AM PST]
>
> It is due to the rx.js, yeoman's dependency, released broken version.
>
> The yeomon mod has patched, but it is still not working yet.
>   After they successfully patch to the right version, try this:

```
npm uninstall -g yo
npm cache clean
npm install -g yo
```

> Here are the related links:
>
> - https://github.com/yeoman/yo/issues/247
> - https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/issues/434

This issue was resolved that day. My answer is no longer relevant...