# Issue with selection options on MAC terminal (scaffloding web application using YOMEN)

Tags: macos, terminal

I am creating a webapp using YOMEN on my new MAC machine, but the terminal does not allows me to select the choices using space key. Here is what I am getting:

=====================================================================

```
     _-----_
    |       |    .--------------------------.
    |--(o)--|    |    Welcome to Yeoman,    |
   `---------´   |   ladies and gentlemen!  |
    ( _´U`_ )    '--------------------------'
    /___A___\    
     |  ~  |     
   __'.___.'__   
 ´   `  |° ´ Y ` 

Out of the box I include HTML5 Boilerplate, jQuery, and a Gruntfile.js to build your app.
? What more would you like? (Press <space> to select)
❯◉ Bootstrap
 ◯ Sass
 ◯ Modernizr


/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/yeoman-environment/node_modules/inquirer/node_modules/rx/dist/rx.all.js:9229
        throw e;
              ^
ReferenceError: parent is not defined
    at AnonymousObserver._onNext (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/yeoman-environment/node_modules/inquirer/node_modules/rx/dist/rx.all.js:4259:63)
    at AnonymousObserver.Rx.AnonymousObserver.AnonymousObserver.next (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/yeoman-environment/node_modules/inquirer/node_modules/rx/dist/rx.all.js:1863:12)
    at AnonymousObserver.Rx.internals.AbstractObserver.AbstractObserver.onNext (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/yeoman-environment/node_modules/inquirer/node_modules/rx/dist/rx.all.js:1795:35)
    at AutoDetachObserverPrototype.next (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/yeoman-environment/node_modules/inquirer/node_modules/rx/dist/rx.all.js:9226:23)
    at AutoDetachObserver.Rx.internals.AbstractObserver.AbstractObserver.onNext (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/yeoman-environment/node_modules/inquirer/node_modules/rx/dist/rx.all.js:1795:35)
    at Subject.Rx.Subject.addProperties.onNext (/Admins-MacBook-Pro-3:V1 jyotipuri$
```

===============================================================

Please help.

Answer (score 4):

<strike>Time of writing: [2014.12.11 1:34AM PST]</strike>

It is due to the rx.js, yeoman's dependency, released broken version.

The yeoman mod has patched, but it is still not working yet.
After they successfully patch to the right version, try this:

```
npm uninstall -g yo
npm cache clean
npm install -g yo
```

Here are the related links:

- https://github.com/yeoman/yo/issues/247
- https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/issues/434

[UPDATE]
- 2014.12.11 4:10AM PST

While yeoman patch is still not working, the fix is PR'ed in RxJS but not merged yet.

Link: https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/commit/dcfcf0f537f6a911ed8fca29edb62f415e17bd76

You can directly change the source code to use yo now.

You'll have to give write permission to */usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/yeoman-environment/node_modules/inquirer/node_modules/rx/dist/rx.all.js*.

And then change the line

```
shouldRun = predicate.call(thisArg, value, count++, parent);
```

to

```
shouldRun = predicate.call(thisArg, value, count++, source);
```

Source: https://github.com/yeoman/yo/issues/247#issuecomment-66600064

[UPDATE]
- 2014.12.11 5:25AM PST]

Issue is fixed! Updated RxJS is submitted to npm.

Run the following commands:

```
npm uninstall -g yo
npm cache clean
npm install -g yo
```

Source: https://github.com/yeoman/yo/issues/247#issuecomment-66617591

Comment: Thanks for this information, I again reinstalled yo but the issue is still there. If you get to know about this issue being fixed, please let me know also.